# Node.js Soap Client outgoing network interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, network-interface

I'm using Node.js' Soap Client (https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) for some extensive integration with other service. However, this is not the only integration running on my server, and I would like to make my calls from another network interface (i.e. "external IP")

My software layer is pretty much complete, but this is something that I've not predicted. Can I possibly do this with some setting, or maybe some Node.js' launch argument?

I was thinking about a locally running proxy server (even in the same thread as the app), but - if possible - I'd welcome some more elegant option.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've managed to achieve this by using request module (https://github.com/request/request) and simply changing one line of code:

```
soap.createClientAsync('https://example.com/service.php?wsdl', {
    'request': request.defaults({
        localAddress: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        connection: 'keep-alive'
    })
})
```